# How create groups with evenly sizes

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql, grouping

I have a table with car information by dates.

```
car_id date       <aditional info>
1      20160101
2      20160102
1      20160103
2      20160104
1      20160105
1      20160106
1      20160107
1      20160108
1      20160109
1      20160110
```

If car has `<= 5` records then will have only one group. `CASE car_id = 2`

if car has `<= 10` records then will have two evenly group. `CASE car_id = 1` order by date

- 20160101 - 20160106  `GROUP 1`
- 20160107 - 20160110  `GROUP 2`

if car has '> 10' then will have three evenly distributed groups.

**DESIRE OUTPUT.**

```
car_id date         group_id
1      20160101        1
1      20160103        1
1      20160105        1
1      20160106        1
------------------------
1      20160107        2
1      20160108        2
1      20160109        2
1      20160110        2
------------------------
2      20160102        1
2      20160104        1
```

I try with `ntile()` but cant make the group number dinamic.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2dd2e/7)

```
SELECT car_id, 
       "date",
       ntile(3) over (partition by car_id order by "date") as group_id
FROM Table1
```

> Bonus Points if can be done direct on `C# LINQ`, otherwise I create a function on postgres.

**aditional info** I will display the historic car information on different colors (groups) So cars with small amount of data will appear with a single color. And max number of colors will be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ntile`:

```
SELECT car_id, "date",
        ntile(CASE WHEN c <= 5 THEN 1
                   WHEN c <= 10 THEN 2
                   ELSE 3
              END)  OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY "date") AS group_id
FROM (SELECT car_id, "date",COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY car_id) AS c
      FROM Table1) AS s
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2dd2e/34/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ car_id ║   date   ║ group_id ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ 20160101 ║        1 ║
║      1 ║ 20160103 ║        1 ║
║      1 ║ 20160105 ║        1 ║
║      1 ║ 20160106 ║        1 ║
║      1 ║ 20160107 ║        2 ║
║      1 ║ 20160108 ║        2 ║
║      1 ║ 20160109 ║        2 ║
║      1 ║ 20160110 ║        2 ║
║      2 ║ 20160102 ║        1 ║
║      2 ║ 20160104 ║        1 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks lad, I came with the same solution after Gordon answer, but couldnt send it because my internet was down. But interesting aproach putting the case inside the `ntile()` I create a subquery for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate the groups manually, using `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when cnt <= 5 then 1
             when car_id * 2 <= cnt then 1
             else 2
        end) as grp
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by date) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by car_id) as cnt
     from table1
    ) t
where cnt <= 10
order by car_id, grp, date;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that answer help me to find the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9c1a/9)**

As Gordon suggest.

- First calculate the number of dates for each `car_id`
- Then assign the number of groups I want depending on `cnt`
- Then use `groups` for the `ntile(grp)` analytic function

.

```
WITH car_dates_count as (
  select t1.*,             
         count(*) over (partition by car_id) as cnt
  from table1 t1
),
car_groups as (
  select cdc.*,
       (case when cnt <= 5  then 1
             when cnt <= 10 then 2
                            else 3
        end) as grp
  from car_dates_count cdc
) 
SELECT *,
       ntile(grp) over (partition by car_id order by "date") as group_id
FROM car_groups;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| car_id |     date | cnt | grp | group_id |
|--------|----------|-----|-----|----------|
|      1 | 20160101 |   9 |   2 |        1 | \
|      1 | 20160102 |   9 |   2 |        1 |  |
|      1 | 20160103 |   9 |   2 |        1 |  |
|      1 | 20160104 |   9 |   2 |        1 |  |
|      1 | 20160105 |   9 |   2 |        1 |  |=> (cnt 9 <= 10) Mean two groups
|      1 | 20160106 |   9 |   2 |        2 |  |
|      1 | 20160107 |   9 |   2 |        2 |  |
|      1 | 20160108 |   9 |   2 |        2 |  |
|      1 | 20160109 |   9 |   2 |        2 | /
--------------------------------------------
|      2 | 20160101 |   5 |   1 |        1 | \
|      2 | 20160102 |   5 |   1 |        1 |  |
|      2 | 20160103 |   5 |   1 |        1 |  |=> (cnt 5 <= 5) Mean one group
|      2 | 20160104 |   5 |   1 |        1 |  |
|      2 | 20160105 |   5 |   1 |        1 | /
--------------------------------------------
|      3 | 20160101 |  16 |   3 |        1 | \
|      3 | 20160102 |  16 |   3 |        1 |  |
|      3 | 20160103 |  16 |   3 |        1 |  |  
|      3 | 20160104 |  16 |   3 |        1 |  |
|      3 | 20160105 |  16 |   3 |        1 |  |
|      3 | 20160106 |  16 |   3 |        1 |  |
|      3 | 20160107 |  16 |   3 |        2 |  |
|      3 | 20160108 |  16 |   3 |        2 |  |=> (cnt 16 > 10) Mean three groups
|      3 | 20160109 |  16 |   3 |        2 |  |
|      3 | 20160110 |  16 |   3 |        2 |  |
|      3 | 20160111 |  16 |   3 |        2 |  |
|      3 | 20160112 |  16 |   3 |        3 |  |
|      3 | 20160113 |  16 |   3 |        3 |  |
|      3 | 20160114 |  16 |   3 |        3 |  |
|      3 | 20160115 |  16 |   3 |        3 |  |
|      3 | 20160116 |  16 |   3 |        3 | /
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `Car` class defined as follows, you could do this using `Linq`.

```
public class Car
{
    public int car_id;
    public DateTime date;       
    // additional info
}
```

We need to apply grouping twice, once on `car_id` and next on when evenly splitting to multiple groups. I prefer using `Linq` for this.

```
    var grouped = cars.GroupBy(c=>c.car_id)
        .Select(c => 
                new 
                {
                    car_grp_id = c.Key,
                    splits = c.Select((s,i)=> 
                    new 
                    {
                        grp_id = i/(c.Count() <= 5 ? 5 :(c.Count() %2 ==0)? c.Count() /2 : (c.Count() /3 +1)),
                        item = s
                    }), 

                })          
        .Select(s=> 
                new 
                {                       
                    grouponcars = s.splits.GroupBy(g=>g.grp_id)
                        .Select(x=>
                        new 
                        {
                            group_id = x.Key,
                            cars = x.Select(y=>y.item)
                        })
                })
        .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/3/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/5/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM
----------------------------------------
groupid : 1 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/7/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 1 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/8/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 1 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/9/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 1 -       Car_Id : 1 -         Date -1/10/2016 12:00:00 AM
----------------------------------------
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 2 -         Date -1/2/2016 12:00:00 AM
groupid : 0 -       Car_Id : 2 -         Date -1/4/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3005f)

Comment: I like some part of your answer and give me some ideas. But as I explain on the question the number of group depend on car.count(). and max number of groups is 3. For your sample each group size is max 4. And groups increase as car.count() go bigger  https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VugsV

Comment: That logic can be derived, let me update to suit the requirement.

Comment: Played with some math :-), check the updated code and demo link.

Comment: I dont want sound ungreatfull because again your code give me some ideas. But this code only create two groups if `count > 10` I think I could make it simple and make a `CASE cars.count` and three select

Comment: That's true, just use some simple switch case and decide group size.

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem, need any assistance?

Comment: Im going on another route. couldnt decipher `grp_id = i/(c.Count() <= 5 ? 5 :(c.Count() %2 ==0)? ....`

Comment: Can you clarify again, what exactly you want in grouping? probably with an example?

Comment: Every car have info on different days .... I want that date data group in `1, 2 or 3` groups depending if `<=5,  <=10, +10` You can read the aditional info at the end of the question. Right Im looking for a `ROW_NUMBER` aproach but still working on it